# C# Custom Serialization for Property

Tags: c#, dynamic, xml-serialization

I'm Serializing a class with XMLSerializer, But for property "MyDynamicObject" alone i want to override  and provide a custom implementation.
How can it be done ?

```
[Serializable]
public class Movie
{
  public string Title
  { get; set; }

  public int Rating
  { get; set; }

  public dynamic MyDynamicObject
  { get; set; }
}


public void SerializeToXML(Movie movie)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Movie));
  TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\movie.xml");
  serializer.Serialize(textWriter, movie);
  textWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is this .net 4.0? Are you not declaring the variables to be used by the properties?

Comment: this is .Net 4 auto implemented properties

Comment: [Auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) are available since .NET 3.0

Comment: Thanks @Serguei... I actually thought they came with 2010

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more details on the 'custom implementation'?

Comment: FYI, `[Serializable]` is not used by the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the [IXMLSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx#Y407) which:

> Provides custom formatting for XML serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to review the list in [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx) and check for 'properties' in the Applies To column.

We can probably help you more if you're more specific with your requirements.

Comment: Consider i want to change the value (Whatever i provided is a sample, in real code there is an unrealizable property where i would like to provide own implementation)

Comment: @user841683 Also make sure you can apply such attributes to the properties, 'cause if my mind ain't playing tricks on me... it's not possible to assign the properties's attributes to the underlying variable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `[OnSerializing()]` attribute on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute.aspx).  There is some sample code at the bottom.

Comment: Looks like XMLSerializer does not support this